# CSS - Menu Text moving out of background

Tags: html, css

Hey guys i am new in CSS so sorry if this is really simple and stupid question, i try to style website from begining, but i just cant get from fail it happend to me  with menu, the text is moving out of background and i cant find why.

It looks like:
http://funedit.com/imgedit/soubory/small_18262058231396865881.jpg

but that text should be in the middle of that blacck background :P

My HTML:

```
  <div id="menu">
    <ul>
     <a href="#"><li>GAMESITES<span id="arrow"></span></li></a>
      <li id="spacer"> </li>
      <a href="#"><li>HRY<span id="arrow"></span></li></a>
      <li id="spacer"> </li>
      <a href="#"><li>SERVERY<span id="arrow"></span></li></a>
      <li id="spacer"> </li>
      <a href="#"><li>CLANKY<span id="arrow"></span></li></a>
      <li id="spacer"> </li>
      <a href="#"><li>FORUM<span id="arrow"></span></li></a>
      <li id="spacer"> </li>
      <a href="#"><li>DOWNLOADS<span id="arrow"></span></li></a>
      <li id="spacer"> </li>
      <a href="#"><li>BLOGY<span id="arrow"></span></li></a>
      <li id="spacer"> </li>
      <a href="#"><li>FLASHOVKY<span id="arrow"></span></li></a>                                                
    </ul> 
  </div>
```

My CSS:

```
#menu{
    background-image: url("images/menubg.png");
    background-repeat: repeat-x;
    height: 44px;
    width: 983px;
    margin: 0 22px;          
}

#spacer{
    background-image: url("images/menu_spacer.png");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    width: 1px;
    height: 48px;
    padding: 0px 0px;
}

#menu ul{
    list-style-position: inside;    /* Bodka v novom riadku vo vnutry */
    list-style-type: none;          /* bez bodky */
}

#menu ul li{   
    padding: 1px 5px 0px 0px;
    display: inline-block;
    color: #f7f7f7;
}
#arrow{
    background-image: url("images/sipka.png");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    width: 10px;
    height: 8px;
    padding-left: 3px;
    display: inline-block; 
}
```

You can find LIVE preview on:
http://funedit.com/andurit/try2/

I will thank you a lot if u can help me to fix it.

Comment: Please validate your HTML markup your UL LI navigation markup is not correct put anchor elements inside li

Comment: your markup is invalid: links can't be immediate children of a list

Comment: Thanks for your comment, i change it but it didnt help me with my main problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#spacer{
    background-image: url("http://funedit.com/andurit/try2/images/menu_spacer.png");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    width: 1px;
    height: 28px;
    padding: 0px 0px;
}
```

The only thing i changed is height in the spacer, it affected your alignment you can check the fiddle and output image for the working Demo

## [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/m3E8B/1/)

[image]

**Live Demo of your page**:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

your problem is in:

```
#spacer {
    height: 48px; }
```

modified the height to 25px or similar.

edited : I recomend you to use a reset css sheet in all your projects.

Comment: It actualy works man, but it change color of my text because is in a href,  can u help me with that as well? I want all text as WHITE

Comment: the color of your text is in: 
#menu ul li {color: #F11717;}.. it should not change when you modified the #spacer height

Comment: it modifed when i changed <a href=""> <li> to <li><a href=""> but never mind i found it, thanks for your answer

Answer (score 0):

Change your **HTML markup** and `define in css` one line `vertical-align:middle` as like this

**HTML Markup**

```
<div id="menu">
    <ul>
    <li><a href="#">GAMESITES</a><span id="arrow"></span></li>
      <li id="spacer"> </li>
     <li><a href="#">HRY</a><span id="arrow"></span></li>
      <li id="spacer"> </li>
     <li><a href="#">SERVERY</a><span id="arrow"></span></li>
      <li id="spacer"> </li>
     <li><a href="#">CLANKY</a><span id="arrow"></span></li>
      <li id="spacer"> </li>
     <li><a href="#">FORUM</a><span id="arrow"></span></li>
      <li id="spacer"> </li>
     <li><a href="#">DOWNLOADS</a><span id="arrow"></span></li>
      <li id="spacer"> </li>
     <li><a href="#">BLOGY</a><span id="arrow"></span></li>
      <li id="spacer"> </li>
     <li><a href="#">FLASHOVKY</a><span id="arrow"></span></li>                                           
    </ul> 
  </div>
```

**Css**

```
#menu ul li{vertical-align:middle;}
```

**[Demo Link](http://jsfiddle.net/DwWVG/1/)**

Answer (score 0):

1) Your markup it's invalid.

You have to do something like that:

```
    <ul>
         <li><a href="#">GAMESITES<span id="arrow"></span></a></li>
          <li id="spacer"> </li>
...
<ul>
```

2) Your problem it's the fixed height of `<list id="spacer">`. **Just remove this property**.
And more, since spacer it's not unique, change **id** with it as a **CLASS**.

3) After that, add a  `line-height` property to your `#menu`

```
#menu {
  line-height: 3.5em;
}
```